# Create custom View with horizontal RecyclerView and a custom border (with movement listener)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a custom view, which represents a horizontal RecyclerView with a border around it. Border's left and right sides could be draggable over RecyclerView items. It's something like UI for video trimming.
As I understand it I need to create something like:

```
public class CustomView extends RecyclerView {
    ....
    onDraw(Canvas cancas) {
      // And there should be code to draw a borders like:
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
      ....
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
[example how it could be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Ghc.jpg)

Inside pink border should be RecyclerView with images inside. This is what I want to do.

Comment: answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037187/4647628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Horizontal View,

`final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

& for border use custom drawable.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't gave enought information. I'd like to do smth like at this picture: [link](http://i64.tinypic.com/fdwzr6.jpg)
but inside pink border should be RecyclerView with images.
I didn't think that custom drawable could help me to build such border.

Maybe I shoul to do this thing in separate classes and then combine inside onde layout xml, so after that merge it and make listeners got right and left border?

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @AlekseyTsukanov using my code you will get horizontal recyclerview for sure, now coming to border stuff is just a view you can develop shape wih stroke and color stuff & mark as accepted answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll try to do this and would let you know about results